# Why does SCNAudioSource stop working after the app is closed and reopened?

Tags: swift, scenekit, playback

When my app is first launched, the following code works as expected, and a sound is played:

```swift
let audioSource = SCNAudioSource(named: "sound.wav")
audioNode.runAction(SCNAction.playAudio(audioSource!, waitForCompletion: false))
```

`audioNode` is a child node of the `SCNScene`, displayed by a `SCNView` named `scnView`.

However, if I close the app, wait a few seconds then reopen it, when the same code is executed, no sound is played.

I have noticed that `scnView.audioEngine.isRunning` is `true` when I first open the app, but becomes `false` upon relaunching it.

The following messages are printed in the console after closing the app:

```
[aurioc] AURemoteIO.cpp:1590:Start: AUIOClient_StartIO failed (561015905)
[avae]   AVAEInternal.h:109   [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1544:Start: (err = PerformCommand(*ioNode, kAUStartIO, NULL, 0)): error 561015905
```

And after reopening the app:

```
[avae] AVAEInternal.h:76    required condition is false: [AVAudioPlayerNode.mm:712:ScheduleBuffer: (_outputFormat.channelCount == buffer.format.channelCount)]
```

I have tried restarting the `scnView.audioEngine`, tried doing `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)` when the app is reopened and `AVAudioSession` interruption is ended, but these did not fix my issue. I encountered the same issue when I tried using `SCNAudioPlayer` instead of `SCNAction.playAudio` as well.

Is this a bug with `SceneKit`/`AVFoundation`, or is there a piece of code that I am missing?

Comment: If you don't get an answer, you might try a spritekit overlay on top of scenekit and use spritekit's audio.  I had a lot of problems - similar to those above, phone call killed game sound, intermittent issues, etc. This was a suggestion someone made to me and it worked pretty well.

Comment: Is there some solution about this issue?